# Delphi XE3 RTF mails

Tags: email, delphi, indy, rtf, delphi-xe3

I would like to send mail with RTF format (including images, with attached files or not).
I have try the following code (with many other ContentType) but I always receive the plain text.
Someone know how to do that with Delphi XE3 ?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  zMessage: TIdMessage;
  zSMTP: TIdSmtp;
begin
  zSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(Application);
  zMessage := TIdMessage.Create;
  zMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'dce@v.com';
  zMessage.Subject := 'Test RTF';
  zMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
//  zMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/alternative';
  zMessage.From.Address := 'dce@v.com';
  zMessage.From.Name := 'DCE';

//  zMessage.Body.LoadFromFile('c:\TEMP\test.rtf');
  with TIdText.Create(zMessage.MessageParts) do
  begin
    ContentType := 'text/richtext';
    Body.LoadFromFile('c:\TEMP\test.rtf');
  end;

  zSMTP.Host := 'm.v.com';
  zSMTP.UserName := 'dce@v.com';
  zSMTP.Password := 'dce';
  zSMTP.Connect;
  zSMTP.Send(zMessage);
end;
```

I have also tried this code :

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  zMBuilder: TIdMessageBuilderRtf;
  zMyMemoryStream: TMemoryStream;
  zMessage: TIdMessage;
  zSMTP: TIdSmtp;
begin
  try
    zSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create(Application);
    zMessage := TIdMessage.Create;
    zMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'dce@v.com';
    zMessage.Subject := 'Test RTF 2';
    zMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
    zMessage.From.Address := 'dce@v.com';
    zMessage.From.Name := 'DCE';

    zMBuilder := TIdMessageBuilderRtf.Create;
    zMyMemoryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    zMBuilder.RtfType := idMsgBldrRtfRichtext;
    zMyMemoryStream.LoadFromFile('c:\TEMP\test.rtf');
    zMBuilder.Rtf.LoadFromStream(zMyMemoryStream);
    zMBuilder.FillMessage(zMessage);

    zSMTP.Host := 'm.v.com';
    zSMTP.UserName := 'dce@v.com';
    zSMTP.Password := 'ddd';
    zSMTP.Connect;
    zSMTP.Send(zMessage);
    zSMTP.DisConnect;
  finally
    zMyMemoryStream.Free;
    zMBuilder.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your email reader even support RTF to begin with? Have you tried other RTF content types? `text/rtf`, `application/rtf`, `text/enriched`, `text/richedit`. Are you trying to mimic Outlook RTF emails? Because Outlook wraps RTF inside of TNEF. HTML is much more commonly supported and widely used.

Comment: Also, when using `TIdMessageBuilder...`, you do not need to assign the `TIdMessage.ContentType` manually, `FillMessage()` will handle that for you. And your `TMemoryStream` is not necessary, you can use `zMBuilder.Rtf.LoadFromFile('c:\TEMP\test.rtf');` instead.